# Can someone explain this sentence? つくろうとしている

Tags: meaning, translation

> つくろうとしている

つくる ー To create
している ー Is doing

What is the うと part?

Comment: You're probably confusing hiragana ろ (ro) and る (ru), by the way.

Comment: Naaa it's volitional form. It is meant to be つくろう

Comment: I was commenting on how you seemed to parse it as つくる + うと + している and it made sense only if you misread the ろ as a る

Answer (score 7):

This is parsed as 作ろう + とする.

作ろう is the [volitional form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Volitional_.28Presumptive.2C_Hortative.29) of 作る. When this form is combined with とする, it gives a meaning of *try to do*. The -ている makes it present progressive.

> 作ろうとしている = To be trying to create